# C++ Constructors Reasoning

Tags: c++

Why is the constructor `H1` and `H2` getting called? Can I get the reason?

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
    char b;

    A()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = '\n';
    }

    A(int a)
    {
        cout << "H1";
    }

    A(char c)
    {
        cout << "H2";
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    char c = 'h';
    A ob1 = a;
    ob1 = c;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear why you expect it not to be called.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/121163/2721883

Comment: @ScottLawson SSCCEs aren't supposed to do anything http://sscce.org/ they just show a simple example of a concept. The question shows a lack of understanding but at the same time C++ is a complex language with a LOT of tutorials about a LOT of different subjects. A pointer as to what tutorials might help would be more useful.

Comment: @couling agree, basic questions should be answered insightfully

Answer (score 4):

```
A ob1 = a;
```

This initialises an object of type `A` from an `int` value. That uses the constructor `A(int)`, printing `H1`.

```
ob1 = c;
```

This assigns a `char` value to the object. Since there isn't a suitable assignment operator `A::operator=(char)`, which could assign the value directly, it does this in two stages:

- Create a temporary object of type `A` from the `char` value
- Assign that to `ob1` using the implicit copy-assignment operator.

The first stage initialises the temporary using the constructor `A(char)`, printing `H2`.

Hence, the output is `H1H2`.

Comment: +1. Just to add two subjects to read up on (search on google)... "Implicit Casting" and "Operator Overloading".

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    int a;
    char b;
    A() {
            a=0;
            b='\n'; 
    }
    A(int a) {
           cout<<"H1";
    }
    A(char c) {
           cout<<"H2";
    } 
}; 

int main() {
    int a=10;
    char c='h';
    A ob1=a; // calls A(int a) because a is typeof int
    ob1=c;  // calls A(char c) because c is typeof char
}
```